# Круговой рейтинг на CSS

Tags: css

Есть рейтинг пользователя. Бальный. От 1 до 100. С шагом в единицу.
Как можно в CSS выводить в виде заполняемого круга количество рейтинга?

Т.е. есть окружность, а в зависимоти от ее заполнения меняется рейтинг, количество баллов.

Как такое можно выводить?

Answer (score 3):

Чистый CSS (Chrome, Internet Explorer 10+, FireFox 5+, Opera 12+):

- [100% pure css radial progress bar](http://fromanegg.com/post/41302147556/100-pure-css-radial-progress-bar)

jQuery:

- [jQuery Knob](http://anthonyterrien.com/knob/) ([github](https://github.com/aterrien/jQuery-Knob))

Случайный фиддл:

- [Circular progress bar](http://jsfiddle.net/oskar/Aapn8/)